# Why border-bottom styling working in the media files in css even after removing it from there ?

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which there are three columns: Name, Type and Status. The HTML code of it is:

```
<div class="dependents">
    <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="cell1">Name</td>
                    <td class="cell2">Type</td>
                    <td class="cell3">Status</td>
                    <td class="cell4 last"></td>
          </tr>
    </tbody> 
</div>
```

The desktop view for this table is:
[image: Desktop View]

My task is to make a mobile view of the same table(between Dependents and Edit sections) of the same page in the following way:

[image: MobileView]

I tried making the mobile view of the page by using the following CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
{
.dependents .table.title td {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

The CSS code(not complete) of the desktop view is:

```
.dependents .table.title td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As shown in the mobile view, it is clearly depicted that the border-bottom in between Name, Type, and Status should not be present in the mobile view in comparison to the desktop view, it is present.

In order to achieve that I have removed the border-bottom line from the mobile CSS code. After removing the border-bottom line, I am still able to see the border bottom section in the mobile view because I believe it is taking the border-bottom of the desktop view. I am not sure how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "desktop view" is not within a media query. It always applies.

The "mobile view" supplements it, it doesn't replace it.

Since you don't override the `border-bottom` property with a different value, the existing rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you code will apply to "desktop view".

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}
```

@media will over-ride the "desktop view" css code IF it satisfies the '@media screen' condition.

You have to re-declare the css for both cases if you want to play safe.

e.g.

```
.table.title.td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Then you override it with

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.table.title.td {
border-bottom: none;
}
}
```

so basically you hv 2 pieces of code:

```
.table.title.td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.table.title.td {
border-bottom: none;
}
}
```

Important Note: declare your "mobile view" css at the end of your css file (as comparative to your normal "desktop view" css code), that way to make sure the "desktop view" code come first and only be over-ridden if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
.dependents .table.title td {
    border-bottom: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

or if that is not working try this

```
.dependents .table.title td {
    border-bottom: none!important;
}
```